# Issue with setting up my playframework application with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, libraries, playframework-2.0

I am new to playframework and after eclipsifying my application and importing it into eclipse, I noticed that all jar dependencies are listed at the root of my app as shown on the following screen capture:

[image: my eclipse environment]

Is there any way to make sure dependencies are listed properly (under referenced libraries) as in this second screen capture:

[image: second screen capture]

Comment: Is this actually a problem, or are you just dissatisfied with where Eclipse shows the JARs in the Package Explorer? What version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess the problem shown in the first screenshot was to use the "Project Explorer". The second screenshot uses the "Package Explorer" which aggregates all referenced libraries under "Referenced Libraries".

Answer (score 3):

You can change the way Eclipse presents these jars by going to the View Menu dropdown in the top-right corner and selecting "Show 'Referenced Libraries' node":

[image: Eclipse screenshot]